# Altering kafka topic - deleting config results in "Invalid config(s): retention.bytes"

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to delete a topic-level configuration `retention.bytes` that was applied on my topic. But when I try to delete the config with the command as described in [Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs) I am getting the following message:

```
kafka-0:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin$ kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --entity-type topics --entity-name foo --alter --delete-config retention.bytes

Invalid config(s): retention.bytes
```

I've already dug into [Kafka's source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConfigCommand.scala) but the only thing it mentions is that it throws this error if "the command if any of the configs to be deleted does not exist". However when I describe my topic, I can see the config there:

```
kafka-0:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin$ kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --describe --topic foo

Topic: foo     PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs: cleanup.policy=compact,delete,flush.ms=1000,segment.bytes=1073741824,retention.ms=7776000000,flush.messages=10000,max.message.bytes=1000012,retention.bytes=1073741824
        Topic: foo     Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,0,1 Isr: 2,1,0
```

So obviously it does exist...

Could anyone pinpoint what the problem could be here?

Comment: You can write the same code to see if the configs are actually there, but how do you know the config isn't already deleted on the topic and isn't coming from the broker? https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConfigCommand.scala#L294

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "coming from the broker"? Yes, the options come from the broker defaults but I should be able to overwrite them once a topic has been created right?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the same thing today, looks like the same issue.
After some tinkering, I figured it out.
First, I was able to add the retention.bytes (I increased it 10 times compare to default 10737418240). After that, I was able to delete it, and it fell back to the default.
So, I think, you can only delete it if you override it yourself. Otherwise it does not have that config, and uses default value. Which means, you cannot make retention size to be unlimited.

Edit:
Overriding the default policy with -1 will enable unlimited retention (do so at your own risk).